# is there a way to edit jasper report list fields from spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports, report

can I remove fields from a jasper report list from inside spring boot app depending on some criteria
and then rearrange the list size or should I use different report template for each criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I created a different report jrxml file for each criteria. this was the best option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).